# filter by field within order_by

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these models:

```
class EntryRank(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey('SomeUser')
    entry = models.ForeignKey('Entry')

class Entry(models.Model):
    feed = models.ForeignKey('RSSFeed')
    title = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    rank = models.ManyToManyField('EntryRank', related_name='entry_rank')
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_ignored = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class RSSFeed(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=500)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=275)
    entries = models.ManyToManyField('Entry', blank=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)

class SomeUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    rss_feeds = models.ManyToManyField('RSSFeed', blank=True)
    words = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

The problem is that I need to sort entries by `rank` and somehow filter ranks by certain user.

Let's say there's 2 users: `User A` and `User B`
There are 2 entries:

```
Entry1: User A: 0.1
Entry1: User B: 0.12
Entry2: User A: 0.06
Entry2: User B: 0.2
```

In this case I need to sort entries **for each user** individually.
So `User A` should see list like:

```
Entry1 Entry2
```

And `User B`:

```
Entry2 Entry1
```

In each case I need to `order_by` by **certain** `EntryRank`s.

So far I have:

```
Entry.objects.all().order_by('-rank__value')
```

Comment: Did you get your answer, if yes than mark as verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
EntryRank.objects.all().exclude(user__user__id = user_id).order_by('-rank', 'user__id')
```

In this case you filter some users with `exclude` clause and order the result by `EntryRank.rank`
You can increase the complexity of exclude clause like:

```
user__user__user__username__in = [auth_user.id1, auth_user.id2,.. ]
```

Once you iterate the results you can get `Entry` and `SomeUsers` references from your `EntryRank` object

```
for entry_rank in EntryRank.objects.all().exclude(user__user__id = user_id).order_by('-rank', 'user__id'):
    entry_rank.value    #rank
    entry_rank.user     #SomeUser
    entry_rank.entry    #Entry
```

Comment: Well, with some changes I think that's a solution. I forgot that I can get list of sorted entries from a list of sorted ranks. This is not exactly the code I used but you gave me the idea. Thank you! And instead of exclude I used filter with opposite condition.